# Pandas combine duplicate items in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like below

```
     Account  APP1    APP2
0      11111   Green   NaN
1      3434    Green   NaN
2      3434    NaN     Green
3      567     Green   NaN
4      980909  Green   NaN
5      980909  NaN     Green
```

Data has an Account number and running status of the application App1 and App2,
I want to combine data of columns where Account is the same for APP1 and APP2

example :

```
     Account  APP1    APP2
0      11111   Green   NaN
1      3434    Green   Green
2      567     Green   NaN
3      980909  Green   Green
```

Comment: `df.groupby("Account").first()` ?

Comment: your example doesn't match with the logic.

Comment: @anky possibly worth noting why this works in case it's not obvious

Comment: @Chris OP did not show what they tried, that's what my guess is :) a clearer [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might clear things up

Comment: @anky definitely, just that it may not be clear it's taking the first non null value is all I was saying :)

Comment: @Chris Absolutely agreed, but again example isnt clear if they dont want this. Until then this might be a dupe IMhumbleO, I am yet to find something though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there can only be one non-nan value for both APP1 and APP2, here is a simple solution to your problem:

```
>>> fn = lambda s: s.dropna().max()
>>> df.groupby(['Account']).agg({'APP1': fn, 'APP2': fn})
          APP1   APP2
Account              
567      Green    NaN
3434     Green  Green
11111    Green    NaN
980909   Green  Green
```

Edit: It seems that anky's comment to your question works as well and has the benefit of being simpler:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Account']).first()
          APP1   APP2
Account              
567      Green    NaN
3434     Green  Green
11111    Green    NaN
980909   Green  Green
```